# How to cut twig correctly

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, twig

I apologize if the question was raised somewhere, and I did not notice the decision.

I have the following files:

```
base.html.twig - which includes css и js. 
blocks.html.twig - which includes blocks. 

en.html.twig
sp.html.twig
ru.html.twig


blocks.html.twig 

    <h1>hello</h1>

    <h2>holla</h2>

    <h3>привет</h3>
```

Please tell me how to initialize the object (for example blocksLang and each h* block to place in this object), for including in different places. For example:

in en.html.twig

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% include "blocks.html.twig"  blocksLang.en %} //and it should render <h1>hello</h1>
```

in sp.html.twig

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% include "blocks.html.twig"  blocksLang.sp %} //and it should render <h2>holla</h2>
```

in ru.html.twig

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% include "blocks.html.twig"  blocksLang.ru %} //and it should render <h3>привет</h3>
```

Thank you for attention

Comment: create a new * .twig file for each block is not an option, because blocks can be added (there will be many files) and extends cannot be more than once.

Comment: perhaps not quite the correct example and translations need to be stored in yml, but still tell me how to correctly include the block part in twig. thank you

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand. Maybe your example is too abstract? Can you maybe explain it differently?

Comment: You are looking it at the wrong way. Instead of creating templates for each languages u should use [translations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html)

Comment: @dbrumann I mean that i need save some blocks in object in base.html.twig and then use this blocks in another files.. so make for each block new twig is bad idea because there may be many.

Comment: @DarkBee yes, I know may be not quite correct examples, but for real I need cut some modules from html as they can some times repeat in project

Comment: You could achieve this with [use](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/use.html) This allows you to (re)use blocks from other templates